# Warning: Failed to find package build-tools 29.0.2: command not found

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, installation, android-sdk-manager

I m trying to get  (build-tools;29.0.2), ndk-bundle, platform-tools and platform version(platforms;android-29).
so I run the command below

```
sdkmanager “build-tools;29.0.2” “ndk-bundle” “platform-tools” “platforms;android-29”
```

AND i got that error

```
Warning: Failed to find package build-tools
29.0.2: command not found
```

can someone help me please

Comment: the downlaod of the build-tools is missing on your computer.
Android Studio Settings -> System Settings -> Android SDK. Activate checkbox in the lower right corner ( = Show Package Details)

Comment: I m downloading on subsystem for linux ,i m following the installation steps showed in this ling https://medium.com/@asnkngt/windows-google-mediapipe-complete-android-setup-guide-2209b279abe4

Answer (score 3):

sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.2" "ndk-bundle" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" (in the example you provided the quotes are wrong)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).